# When finished "looping" Select first cell in range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a script that loops through sections on one sheet (*Function Test Procedure*) and pastes those values into another sheet (*Results*) in cell L2.

The way it is currently set up is to loop for the number of sections, copy and paste those values to the *Results sheet* and select the next empty cell in column L.

That works just fine, as long as the button is not pressed multiple times, because when the button is pressed multiple times, it will add the copied results under the results that were already there.

What I want to do is modify the script to loop through the available sections and then select cell L2 to paste the updated results over the existing results if the button is pressed numerous times.

This should be simple, but I cannot figure it out.  Also, the desired range has been named "ATPResults."

```
Sub Copy_ATP_Tables()

 Dim SectionATP As Long, NextRow As Long

  For SectionATP = 1 To 35 '36

    NextRow = Sheets("Results").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Next empty row

    Sheets("Acceptance Test Procedure").Range("APTSec" & SectionATP).Columns("A:H").Copy _
    Destination:=Sheets("Results").Range("L" & NextRow) 'SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

'        Range("FTPSec" & Section).Columns("G:H").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
'            Destination:=Sheets("Results").Range("N" & NextRow)

  Next SectionATP

'    Sheets("Results").Range("ATPResults").Select
'    For SectionATP = 35 To 35

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your question, I modified it so it always start at `L2`:

```
Sub Copy_ATP_Tables()

 Dim SectionATP As Long, NextRow As Long
 NextRow = Sheets("Results").Range("L" & 2) 'This line defines where to start 

  For SectionATP = 1 To 35 '36

    Sheets("Acceptance Test Procedure").Range("APTSec" & SectionATP).Columns("A:H").Copy _
    Destination:=Sheets("Results").Range("L" & NextRow) 'SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    NextRow = Sheets("Results").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Moved to the end of the loop

  Next SectionATP
End Sub
```